# Ubuntu 22.04 devices failure

Tags: uefi, 22.04, network-manager, bluetooth

Having Ubuntu 22.04 as an original OS I had to enter paragon hard disk manager. After reboot an error occurred showing message about UEFI error. After paragon drive removal and reboot no network is found, Bluetooth is not working and 2 monitors are considered as a single one. Soes anybody know what can issue this?

Comment: tray reinstall the drivers for this not working devices